# Making a $window.location.reload(true); execute only once in Ionic/Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to execute this code to reset my app when it goes to the app homepage. It works but obviously loops round as it reloads and reloads. What javascript do I need to add to get it to execute only once when it enters the page?

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function() {
**$window.location.reload(true);**
})
})
```

Comment: Maybe create a cookie, clear before reload, check for existence of cookie on subsequent page loads?

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the event (it could be firing multiple times) and not in the reload instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$route.reload();
```

this should work.

Comment: Would I need to add $route to or $rootScope to the list of functions on the first line?